# How to disable/enable controllers in JMVC?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, javascriptmvc

Imagine you have one page app using Javascript MVC, which should switch between sub-apps and still stay on the same page. You can load additional controllers and views into the page, but to avoid the conflicts between different controllers, you need to enable the current controller and disable others. You can even destroy the controller and add the current sub-app controllers if needed.

Is it possible? if so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you have some kind of hierarchy on your page (e.g. a page controller, some for navigation etc.) and you only replace the controllers of the part of your page that actually changes.

For a central content element that means either destroying the controllers (by calling destroy on it) or replacing the element that will change (which will remove the controller attached to it as well). So you don't really need to disable anything because you are actually removing the whole thing.